# Производительность nginx при верификации клиентского сертификата

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls, авторизация

Планирую использовать `nginx` с настройкой верификации клиентского сертификата.
Будет настроен локальный УЦ со списком отзыва, доступным по HTTPs. Думаю, что каждое соединение клиента будет верифицироваться, а клиентский сертификат проверяться на отзыв дополнительным запросом от nginx к самому себе. Если я прав, то производительность может снизиться в части проверки сертификата.

Отсюда вопрос - насколько будет снижение производительности? Может кто-то уже проводил такие тесты?